# log4net troubleshooting with Database in C# ConsoleApp

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, log4net

I am new to logging in .Net and was trying to learn log4net as a logging tool. I am running into a problem which is
I have created a log4net config file and trying to add values of logs into SSMS but values are not populating as expected. Here is my log4net config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<log4net>
    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date %5level %logger.%method [%line] - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="DatabaseAppender" type="ToolsCommon.logging.AdoNetAppender">
        <filter type="log4net.Filter.LoggerMatchFilter">
            <loggerToMatch value="Startup" />
            <acceptOnMatch value="false" />
        </filter>
        <bufferSize value="1" />
        <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />0
        <connectionString value="dynamicly created" />
        <commandText value="INSERT INTO Log ([EntryID],[Message],[TimeStamp],[SeverityId]) VALUES (@entryid,  @message, @log_date, @severityId)" />
        <parameter>
            <parameterName value="@entryid" />
            <dbType value="String" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                
                <conversionPattern value="%entryid" />
            </layout>
        </parameter>
        
        <parameter>
            <parameterName value="@log_date" />
            <dbType value="DateTime" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
        </parameter>
        <parameter>
            <parameterName value="@message" />
            <dbType value="String" />
            <size value="4000" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%message" />
            </layout>
        </parameter>
        
        <parameter>
            <parameterName value="@severityId" />
            <dbType value="Int64" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <converter>
                    <name value="severityId" />
                    <type value="ToolsCommon.logging.QCSeverityConverter" />
                </converter>
                <conversionPattern value="%severityId" />
            </layout>
        </parameter>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FileAppender" type="ToolsCommon.logging.CustomFileAppender">
        <file value="%property{logFilePath}/ToolLog.log" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date %5level %logger.%method [%line] - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="ALL"/>
        <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
        <appender-ref ref="DatabaseAppender" />
        <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
    </root>
</log4net>
```

Issue with above code is EntryID is not getting populated as expected rather it gets populated with some other value which I have no idea where that value is coming from.

Is there any way I can debug this and find out how EntryID value is populated?

I tried debugging it but since this is a config file I cannot debug it using Visual Studios debugger. I think this is getting invoked as and when logger is called but I am not sure where EntryId value is coming from? I am expecting any clue so I can figure out how EntryId is getting populated.

Comment: You are correct to use the configuration template provided by log4net itself. But there are many factors that affect the value obtained. Can you tell me what database are you using? Also can you provide the code of your entity class?

Comment: I am using SQL Server as DB

Comment: I am not using Entity Framework ? or can you tell me where I can possibly find this?

Comment: Hi, I post a new answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn on internal debugging with:

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

see [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html) for more info.

Comment: I added this in App.config file but the internal logs which I am expecting to be in files are not coming. Am I missing anything?

Comment: The log4net debug messages go to the console, if you're not using a console app you have to setup a trace listener. Please read the "How do I enable log4net internal debugging?" section of the link I provided.

Answer (score 0):

Please edit your configuration file according to this format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net"  type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,
            log4net-net-1.0" />
  </configSections>

  <log4net>
    ..
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This is not working it is not generating log file at all.

Comment: Is there a way I can append the output of the Debugger to text file